# Jenkins building with GitLab has an error which is."Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job."

Tags: jenkins

I created new project in jenkins and made it freestyle project.
So here is my question, I have set every details and I created a parameter which is

```
branchName
//I can input string here.
//input ex)develop
```

This does not work with this error message

**

> ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and
> branch configuration for this job.

**

I googled about this, but most of answers were just changing */master -> */main.
Finally I came stackoverflow and asking this question.

BTW It works fine if I don't select specific branch.
However, it builds every branch in origin repository(there are dozens of branches)
so I must specify which branch to build. Thanks.

Comment: Please share more details of your job configuration

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.